# Python multiprocessing and networking on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, sockets, networking

I'm trying to implement a tcp 'echo server'.
Simple stuff:

1. Client sends a message to the server.
2. Server receives the message
3. Server converts message to uppercase
4. Server sends modified message to client
5. Client prints the response.

It worked well, so I decided to parallelize the server; make it so that it could handle multiple clients at time.
Since most Python interpreters have a GIL, multithreading won't cut it.
I had to use multiproces... And boy, this is where things went downhill.

I'm using Windows 10 x64 and the WinPython suit with Python 3.5.2 x64.

My idea is to create a socket, intialize it (bind and listen), create sub processes and pass the socket to the children.
But for the love of me... I can't make this work, my subprocesses die almost instantly.
Initially I had some issues 'pickling' the socket...
So I googled a bit and thought this was the issue. 
So I tried passing my socket thru a multiprocessing queue, through a pipe and my last attempt was 'forkpickling' and passing it as a bytes object during the processing creating.
Nothing works.

Can someone please shed some light here?
Tell me whats wrong?
**Maybe the whole idea (sharing sockets) is bad... And if so, PLEASE tell me how can I achieve my initial objective: enabling my server to ACTUALLY handle multiple clients at once (on Windows)** (don't tell me about threading, we all know python's threading won't cut it ¬¬)

It also worth noting that no files are create by the debug function.
No process lived long enough to run it, I believe.

The typical output of my server code is (only difference between runs is the process numbers):

```
Server is running...
Degree of parallelism: 4
Socket created.
Socket bount to: ('', 0)
Process 3604 is alive: True
Process 5188 is alive: True
Process 6800 is alive: True
Process 2844 is alive: True

Press ctrl+c to kill all processes.

Process 3604 is alive: False
Process 3604 exit code: 1
Process 5188 is alive: False
Process 5188 exit code: 1
Process 6800 is alive: False
Process 6800 exit code: 1
Process 2844 is alive: False
Process 2844 exit code: 1
The children died...
Why god?
WHYYyyyyy!!?!?!?
```

The server code:

```
# Imports
import socket 
import packet
import sys
import os
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing as mp
import pickle
import io

# Constants
DEGREE_OF_PARALLELISM = 4
DEFAULT_HOST = ""
DEFAULT_PORT = 0

def _parse_cmd_line_args():
    arguments = sys.argv
    if len(arguments) == 1:
        return DEFAULT_HOST, DEFAULT_PORT
    else:
        raise NotImplemented()

def debug(data):
    pid = os.getpid()
    with open('C:\\Users\\Trauer\\Desktop\\debug\\'+str(pid)+'.txt', mode='a',
              encoding='utf8') as file:
        file.write(str(data) + '\n')

def handle_connection(client):
    client_data = client.recv(packet.MAX_PACKET_SIZE_BYTES)
    debug('received data from client: ' + str(len(client_data)))
    response = client_data.upper()
    client.send(response)    
    debug('sent data from client: ' + str(response))

def listen(picklez):    
    debug('started listen function')

    pid = os.getpid()
    server_socket = pickle.loads(picklez)
    debug('acquired socket')

    while True:
        debug('Sub process {0} is waiting for connection...'.format(str(pid)))

        client, address = server_socket.accept()
        debug('Sub process {0} accepted connection {1}'.format(str(pid),
              str(client)))

        handle_connection(client)        
        client.close()
        debug('Sub process {0} finished handling connection {1}'.
              format(str(pid),str(client)))

if __name__ == "__main__":    
#   Since most python interpreters have a GIL, multithreading won't cut
#   it... Oughta bust out some process, yo!
    host_port = _parse_cmd_line_args()
    print('Server is running...')
    print('Degree of parallelism: ' + str(DEGREE_OF_PARALLELISM))

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print('Socket created.')

    server_socket.bind(host_port)
    server_socket.listen(DEGREE_OF_PARALLELISM)
    print('Socket bount to: ' + str(host_port))        

    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    mp.reduction.ForkingPickler(buffer).dump(server_socket)
    picklez = buffer.getvalue()

    children = []
    for i in range(DEGREE_OF_PARALLELISM):        
        child_process = mp.Process(target=listen, args=(picklez,))
        child_process.daemon = True
        child_process.start()
        children.append(child_process)

        while not child_process.pid:
            sleep(.25)

        print('Process {0} is alive: {1}'.format(str(child_process.pid), 
              str(child_process.is_alive())))     
    print()    

    kids_are_alive = True
    while kids_are_alive:
        print('Press ctrl+c to kill all processes.\n')
        sleep(1) 

        exit_codes = []
        for child_process in children:
            print('Process {0} is alive: {1}'.format(str(child_process.pid), 
              str(child_process.is_alive())))
            print('Process {0} exit code: {1}'.format(str(child_process.pid), 
              str(child_process.exitcode)))
            exit_codes.append(child_process.exitcode)

        if all(exit_codes):
            # Why do they die so young? :(
            print('The children died...')
            print('Why god?')
            print('WHYYyyyyy!!?!?!?')
            kids_are_alive = False
```

edit: fixed the signature of "listen". My processes still die instantly.

edit2: User cmidi pointed out that this code does work on Linux; so my question is: *How can I 'made this work' on Windows?*

Comment: multiprocessing handles passing sockets to child processes automatically. The Windows implementation uses the socket `share` method and `fromshare` function.

Comment: Call `accept()` in the main process and pass the resulting `(conn, addr)` tuple to a worker using a shared `multiprocessing.Queue`.

Comment: No change, eryksun. My proceses still die instantly.

Comment: Please show the latest version where you're not doing this incorrect pickling procedure. Just pass the socket directly as an argument to the target function or in a `multiprocessing.Queue`. There's more -- a lot more -- to sending a socket between Windows processes, but you don't need to worry about it because multiprocessing already does all of this work for you.

Comment: FYI, your code works fine with a simple change to use `mp.Process(target=listen, args=(server_socket,))`, with `listen` modified to take the socket as a parameter.

Comment: On windows? Because cmidi said this code does work, but on linux. This code doesn't work on my machine, running Windows.

Comment: It worked fine for me 5 hours ago, given the changes I mentioned. It loops repeatedly showing all 4 processes are alive, and each log file shows the process is waiting for a connection.

Comment: Can you please post the working code? Maybe on pastebin?

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/jw7CP7hU) works for me.

Comment: @eryksun, I have no idea what was wrong with my original code. But I started from scratch and followed your suggestion of passing the socket to the Process constructor and it's working now. If you post your suggestion as a answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly pass a socket to a child process. multiprocessing registers a reduction for this, for which the Windows implementation uses the following `DupSocket` class from `multiprocessing.resource_sharer`:

```
class DupSocket(object):
    '''Picklable wrapper for a socket.'''
    def __init__(self, sock):
        new_sock = sock.dup()
        def send(conn, pid):
            share = new_sock.share(pid)
            conn.send_bytes(share)
        self._id = _resource_sharer.register(send, new_sock.close)

    def detach(self):
        '''Get the socket.  This should only be called once.'''
        with _resource_sharer.get_connection(self._id) as conn:
            share = conn.recv_bytes()
            return socket.fromshare(share)
```

This calls the Windows socket [`share`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.share) method, which returns the protocol info buffer from calling [`WSADuplicateSocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741565). It registers with the resource sharer to send this buffer over a connection to the child process. The child in turn calls `detach`, which receives the protocol info buffer and reconstructs the socket via `socket.fromshare`.

It's not directly related to your problem, but I recommend that you redesign the server to instead call `accept` in the main process, which is the way this is normally done (e.g. in Python's [`socketserver.ForkingTCPServer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.ForkingTCPServer) module). Pass the resulting `(conn, address)` tuple to the first available worker over a `multiprocessing.Queue`, which is shared by all of the workers in the process pool. Or consider using a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) with `apply_async`.

Comment: I see. What about [this](http://pastebin.com/uRjCBuaD) approach, is it legitimate?

Comment: I haven't checked how the backlog is handled when the listening socket is copied to another process. If each copy has its own backlog, then it's probably not what you want.

Comment: I see. Last question and I stop bothering you, hehe. Do you know where can I find some documentation about this?

Answer (score 0):

`def listen()` the target/start for your child processes does not take any argument but you are providing serialized socket as an argument  `args=(picklez,)` to the child process this would cause an exception in the child process and exit immediately.

```
TypeError: listen() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

`def listen(picklez)` should solve the problem this will provide one argument to the target of your child processes.

Comment: Indeed, the function originally posted wasn't complete. I posted an incomplete / incorrect code here.
The correct signature is listen(picklez). My point is: sadly this isn't the problem; the original code has the correct signature but my children processes still die instantly, but thank you for the answer.

Comment: strictly speaking `accept` should be locked between different processes access and the code seems to be working on a linux environment even without serializing the socket

Comment: I was afraid about this... I had a feeling this was a Windows complication.
I will add this information to my quesiton. Thank you cmidi.

Comment: what happens if you change `debug` to just `print(data)` rather than opening the file

Comment: Nothing happens. I thought it was some sort of io-flushing issue... That's why I decided to create a file.